# Opencart - Auto Disable "out of stock" Products

Tags: php, sql, opencart

I'm looking for something more advanced than viewtopic.php?t=7080

I need to hide (or disable) products that are out of stock AND are in a specific category.

This problem arose because I have a category called "Clearance" and I want clearance items to automatically disable after selling out, as we'll never get more in stock. At the same time I want products in all other categories to continue to display after being out of stock.

Please help.
Mike

Answer (score 1):

I would do this inside the confirm method of the order model. This is where quantities for products are updated once a sale is confirmed.

Open:

`catalog/model/checkout/order.php`

Within the confirm() method you'll find a line like:

`foreach ($order_product_query->rows as $order_product) {`

You could create a new method that would return the existing quantity for the given product, subtract the sold amount and check to see if the new quantity is 0, plus it would check if the product is attached to your given category.

If so, then set the product status to disabled if you don't want it to show at all, or set the stock_status to Out of Stock if you just want to show that it's sold out.

```
// check quantity and categories
private function checkQuantity ($product_id) {
    $return = array();

    // first check if product is attached to your specified category and add boolean to array
    $categories = $this->db->query ("SELECT category_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
    if (in_array($your_clearance_category_id, $categories->rows)):
        $return['check'] = true;
    else:
        $return['check'] = false;
    endif;

    // get your pre-sale quantity and add to array
    $quantity = $this->db->query ("SELECT quantity FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
    $return['quantity'] = $quantity->row['quantity'];

    return $return;
}
```

Then add this just after the opening of your `foreach ($order_product_query->rows as $order_product) {` structure:

```
$checks = $this->checkQuantity($order_product['product_id']);
if ($checks['check']):
    if (((int)$check['quantity'] - (int)$order_product['quantity']) <= 0):
        $this->db->query ("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET status = '0' WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$order_product['product_id'] . "'");
    endif;
endif;
```

Haven't tested but it should work with or without a couple tweaks.

Comment: This might work well but I guess it is unnecessary to get all the categories and check whether the product is linked also to the `clearance` one - the clearance products should be linked to `clearance` category only - therefore one useless SQL query per loop run is removed. But I would think of the disabling within the confirm step - as order still might not be paid, delivered, picked-up, etc. thus the products should be available again... If You disable them here and the order got declined, the products would have to be enabled manually...

Comment: Actually, you will need to check each product. Category info is not stored with a product, neither is manufacturer, so for each product sold in a given order, you'd need to check to see which categories have been assigned to each product. Yes, you'd need to re-enable the product, but you're already going to have to adjust the quantity if an order is not paid. There's no way for your web server to know if you actually received the money, or an item has been picked up. It can only go by the response returned from your payment venue.